# Minimise full screen Steam games in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, games, window-manager

Previously, in OS X Mavericks it worked to minimise games, or navigate through open apps with cmd+tab even if the game was opened in full screen but now you can't do that anymore. Pressing cmd+tab doesn't have any effect. Also I can't find any way to minimise the game.

I don't really know whether this problem is only for steam games or any other game, as I don't have any non-steam game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience it depends on the Game-programmer itself and has nothing to do with Steam, f.e. I recently bought 'Lords of Xulima' on Steam and the Game-Developer has disabled any Non-Fullscreen features.

Sometimes there is a trick though: With the game running, try pressing cmd+alt+esc. That will open the 'force quit'-window which then enables you to use cmd-tab.

Try it with your game.

Comment: Thanks, that's a real nice workaround! Too bad it's not something built in like Windows has...

Answer (score 3):

`CMD`+`H` seems to work too.

Strangly `CMD`+`M`does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have found following trick - pressed SHIFT-TAB (what just brought steam window over the game in full screen mode, without ability to switch to any other app: both ALT-TAB and desktop switch did not work) and then clicked on "Controller Configuration", what brought window with dialog that there is no controller attached but this time on a new  desktop called "Steam" which properly handles ALT-TAB and Desktop Switch. This is on Sierra.